# Add custom text in qweb report odoo9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, qweb

How add custom text in inherit qweb?

For example in Sale/view/report_saleorder.xml

below **class="oe_structure"** i need one table

```
<p t-field="doc.note" />
            <p t-if="doc.payment_term_id.note">
                <span t-field="doc.payment_term_id.note"/>
            </p>
            <p t-if="not doc.payment_term_id and doc.partner_id.property_payment_term_id">
                <span t-field="doc.partner_id.property_payment_term_id.note"/>
            </p>
            <p id="fiscal_position_remark" t-if="doc.fiscal_position_id and doc.fiscal_position_id.note">
                <strong>Fiscal Position Remark:</strong>
                <span t-field="doc.fiscal_position_id.note"/>
            </p>
            <div class="oe_structure"/>


    <xpath expr="???" position="???">
           <table><tr><td>CUSTOM TEXT</td></tr></table>
    </xpath>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if the above xml is the whole report however you could use something like this.

```
<xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_structure'][last()]" position="after">
    <!-- YOUR TABLE HERE -->
</xpath>
```

This assumes this is the last instance of oe_structure in the xml you are inheriting from.

Comment: Thanks for help, only before class I'm add @  --> @class

Comment: Oh yes,. I will correct this. I am still just waking up. Have not finished my coffee yet.